# Npm run dev not working with laravel 6

Tags: npm

`$ npm install
npm WARN rollback Rolling back readable-stream@2.3.6 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\xampp\htdocs\testingnpmrundev\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "7.*",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    }
}

added 1011 packages from 486 contributors and audited 17161 packages in 267.827s
found 0 vulnerabilities`$ npm run dev

> @ dev C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel6
>   npm run development

'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Comment: Please share your `package.json` file! Otherwise this error is pretty hard to pinpoint. I've never used Laravel but according to the docs you probably aren't calling the right command from your terminal. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix#running-mix says that the command to start the webpack server is `npm run dev`. Not `npm run development`. That's a shot in the dark though.

Comment: Didn't see this til now but it seems that something is calling the `development` script from somewhere. However your post doesn't really elaborate on the system you're running or the shell you're using. *(Which looks like Windows to me...)*